# Windows Phone - Upload Text to FTP Server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ftp

Just wondering what would be the best way to upload a string to a FTP server using C# for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: geez .. what did on say on the title? did it say WPF? Windows Forms? ASP.NET?